# Добавить исключения директорий в find

Tags: linux, find

Есть команда, которая сохраняет права доступов к файлам и директориям linux в файл

```
find / -depth -exec stat --format '%a %u %g %n' {} + > /save-the-list
```

Необходимо добавить в исключения вот такой список директорий

```
dev/
proc/
sys/
run/
```

Подскажите плиз, как это можно сделать? Пробовал использовать с ключиком *-prune* , но как я понял из вывода, *-prune* не работает с *-depth*

Еще пробовал так

```
find / -depth \( -path /dev -o -path /run \) -exec stat --format '%a %u %g %n' {} + > /save-the-list
```

Но тоже не то..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самое простое, если в именах директорий в корне нет пробелов, то можно как-то так:

```
find $(ls / | grep -Ev '^(dev|proc|sys|run)$') -depth -exec stat ...
```

Если подзакладываться на пробелы, то можно что-то такое соорудить:

```
ls / | grep -Ev '^/(dev|proc|sys|run)$' | while read d; do find "$d" -depth -exec stat ... ; done
```

Менее эффективный вариант, но учитывающий пробелы (и переводы строк) и ограничивающийся одним `find`'ом:

```
find / -! \( -path '/dev/*' -o -path '/proc/*' ... \) -depth -exec stat ...
```

Comment: Спасибо @Fat-Zer, решил таки ограничиться find'ом:))

Answer (score 1):

Для исключения каталога и его вложения из поиска и вывода программой `find` следует указывать параметры поиска `-not -path '/path*'`, если нужно оставить каталог но исключить его содержимое, то указываем `'/path/*'`, если нужно убрать каталог, но оставить содержимое, то указываем `'/path'`

---

Важно:
При исключении каталога и его содержимого `'/path*'` - дополнительно могут быть исключены каталоги по маске, т.е. если прописать `/work*`, то будут исключены `/work` `/workdir` `/working` и т.д.

---

Дополнительно, внешнюю программу `stat` можно не использовать, данные можно получить стандартным параметром `-printf`

Пример:

```
find / \
-not -path '/dev*' \
-not -path '/proc*' \
-not -path '/sys*' \
-not -path '/run*' \
-printf '%m %U %G %p\n'
```

Пример 2:

```
find / -not \( -path '/dev*' -o -path '/proc*' -o -path '/sys*' -o -path '/run*' \) -printf '%m %U %G %p\n'
```